# Как заменить элементы двумерного списка в соответствии с данными из словаря?

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

Имеются словарь и двумерный список:

```
a = {'loc01': 'moscow',
    'loc02': 'piter', 
    'loc03': 'new_york'}

b = [['john', 'loc01'], 
     ['sam', 'loc01'], 
     ['bob', 'loc03'], 
     ['bill', 'loc01'], 
     ['jim', 'loc02']]
```

Нужно на основе словаря и списка создать новый список вида:

```
total = [['john', 'loc01', 'moscow'], 
         ['sam', 'loc01', 'moscow'], 
         ['bob', 'loc03', 'new_york'], 
         ['bill', 'loc01', 'moscow'], 
         ['jim', 'loc02', 'piter']]
```

Т.е. сравнить ключ:значение в словаре `a`, и если в списке `b` есть элемент строки, название которого равно названию ключа, то добавить к списку `b` соответствующее ключу значение словаря в новом списке `total`.

Comment: Переберите все пары в списке и для каждой проверьте, есть ли данная локация в словаре. Если есть, то добавьте город, если нет, то не добавляйте ничего

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = [x + [a.get(x[1])] for x in b]
```

результат:

```
[['john', 'loc01', 'moscow'],
 ['sam', 'loc01', 'moscow'],
 ['bob', 'loc03', 'new_york'],
 ['bill', 'loc01', 'moscow'],
 ['jim', 'loc02', 'piter']]
```

---

проверка для случая когда в `a` нет соответствующего элемента:

```
In [13]: b
Out[13]:
[['john', 'loc01'],
 ['sam', 'loc01'],
 ['bob', 'loc03'],
 ['bill', 'loc01'],
 ['jim', 'loc02'],
 ['max', 'loc99']]

In [14]: res = [x + [a.get(x[1])] for x in b]

In [15]: res
Out[15]:
[['john', 'loc01', 'moscow'],
 ['sam', 'loc01', 'moscow'],
 ['bob', 'loc03', 'new_york'],
 ['bill', 'loc01', 'moscow'],
 ['jim', 'loc02', 'piter'],
 ['max', 'loc99', None]]    #   <------ Note!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(a, b):
    return [b[i] + ([a[b[i][1]]] if b[i][1] in a else [None]) for i in range(len(b))]
```